# Give input type max limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a input type like this:

```
<input name="adult-count" type="text" data-perunit="2500" data-maxunits="5" class="up-down-spinner" value="0">
```

With data-maxunits. I set with javascript the max of the input. The input type is a spinner and you can going down and up with arrows. 
If you exceed the max unit goes. You can not further click. But you can still enter a number that is greater.

How can I make. The input that you type up the number to enter. Limit to the data-maxunit.

Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you using [`<input type="number">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#number-state)?

Comment: It must be working on alle browsers. Also ie7

Comment: Why aren't you starting with `<input type="number">` and layering JavaScript on top of that for browsers which don't support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind an event onChange, to check if the value is greater then data-maxunits and if it is change it back to data-maxunits, like so:

```
document.getElementById('adult-count').addEventListener('change', function(e){
   var input = e.target;
   var maxunits = parseInt(input.getAttribute('data-maxunits'), 10);
   if(parseInt(input.value, 10) > maxunits)
      input.value = maxunits;
}, 1);
```

Comment: oh, if it's for IE7 also, addEventListener won't work, you will have to fallback with attachEvent('onChange', function())

Comment: This is not working. It is not working in chrome and new browsers

Comment: of course, because your input does not have the attribtue id set to 'adult-count'. try adding id="adult-count"

Comment: I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null